# Why are good() and is_open() returning true on Mac if a file does not exist?

Tags: c++, xcode, fstream

On Windows (using gcc), the following code prints `0 0` as expected **if the filename passed is the path of an existing directory**, ie a path without an actual file (in fact, no file can be opened for reading).

On Mac (using Xcode), it prints `1 1` instead! How it is possible? Why do both `good()` and `is_open()` return `true` on Mac? Is Xcode clib buggy, or am I ignoring some detail?

```cpp
#include <fstream>

int main(void)
{
    std::ifstream file("filename", std::ios::binary);

    cout << file.good() << " " << file.is_open();
}
```

Comment: What does it tell you (on Mac) if you use `std::ios::binary | std::ios::in`?

Comment: @rturrado -- that shouldn't matter; `std::ifstream` is an input stream, even when you specify additional options.

Comment: @PeteBecker Correct, thanks!

Comment: I suspect that some Unix-based systems allow you to successfully open a handle to a folder as if it was a regular file. You can use [`std::filesystem::is_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_directory) to check if the path is a folder.

Comment: If you have a directory named `filename`, on some operating systems you can open that directory *as a file* and read from it.  It will contain its content items (in a binary format).  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: @all Thanks, that was actually the only thing I could suspect. The directory is opened as though it were a file on mac it seems. Imho that does not make much sense and it is definitely a bad thing that there is no standardized behaviour. So even fopen() would likely have the same problem. Sadly I have not a mac and cannot try personally, I asked a volounteer to make a porting of a program of mine and he encountered this unexpected annoyance

Comment: Btw I wanted to avoid std::filesystem if possible because for that c++17 is needed. Is there any other portable way to decide whether a path contains a valid file to be opened for reading ?

Comment: @elena If you aren't allowed to use C++17 then another portable choice (to replace `std::filesystem`) would be the [Boost.Filesystem library](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/). Those two can usually be directly replaced with each other (except maybe in some rare corner cases).

Comment: @Eljay: no definitely not. I just want to open a file for reading but if the filename passed is invalid (either pointing to a nonexisting file or to a directory) the program must fail

Comment: You may want to check the [`file_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/file_type) to ensure that the path does not refer to a directory.

Comment: Thanks Eljay I will have a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood:

- on Windows, `ifstream` will ultimately end up using `CreateFile()`, which can open a directory *only* if the `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` flag is specified, which `ifstream` is not likely to use.
- on other platforms, `ifstream` is likely using `fopen()`, which can open a directory as long as the requested access is read-only, which is true for an `ifstream`.